# Biblatex how to reduce spacing before and after a prenote?

Tags: spacing, biblatex

I'm using Biblatex and biber. How is it possible to reduce the spacing before and after a pre note?

### Edited:

Here is as MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@THESIS{a,
  AUTHOR =  {Myself},
  TITLE = {Me, myself and I},
  Institution = {My University},
  type = {Ph.D. thesis},
  date = {2010-11-25}
}
%  year = {2010} 
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage[backend=biber,defernumbers=true,sorting=ydnt]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\defbibnote{AA}{\underline{Here is a prenote}}

\begin{document}
Hello world.

    \nocite{*}
    \printbibliography[heading=none,resetnumbers=true,prenote=AA]
    \printbibliography[heading=none,resetnumbers=true,prenote=AA]
    \printbibliography[heading=none,resetnumbers=true,prenote=AA]
\end{document}
```

@moewe is right. The spacing before a prenote is handled by what is happening before. If there is no space between "Hello World" and \nocite, then the prenote is in the same paragraph as "Hello World".

So I reformulate. Inside a biblio (like between the second and the third citations) in the MWE, how can I set the spacing before a prenote.

How can I set the spacing after a prenote?

Comment: Could you please show us an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) of what you got so far and which style you use? I'm fairly certain you can change the space after the prenote, but the space before is not from `biblatex`, but from the text surrounding the citation, so that might be harder.

Comment: If you don't know how to create a minimal working example with bibliography, see [MWEB](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/4407).

Comment: Can you also show us an example use case of what you are thinking of (a 'mock-up' maybe)? I really don't think this is a particularly good idea, but it might depend on the style and the exact use case if and how bad it is.

Comment: I see we were talking about entirely different prenotes, thanks for that MWE.

Answer (score 1):

The vertical space is just the space before and after the first and last item of the bibliography. But you can manipulate it, e.g., with `\vskip` either in the note or between the `\printbibliography`. The horizontal space before the note is the normal paragraph indent and can be removed using `\noindent` again either between the `\printbibliography` or in the note:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@THESIS{a,
  AUTHOR =  {Myself},
  TITLE = {Me, myself and I},
  Institution = {My University},
  type = {Ph.D. thesis},
  date = {2010-11-25}
}
%  year = {2010} 
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage[backend=biber,defernumbers=true,sorting=ydnt]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\defbibnote{AA}{\underline{Here is a prenote}}
\defbibnote{BB}{\vskip-2ex\noindent\underline{Here is a prenote}\vskip-1ex}

\begin{document}
Hello world.

    \nocite{*}
    \printbibliography[heading=none,resetnumbers=true,prenote=AA]
    \vskip -2ex\noindent
    \printbibliography[heading=none,resetnumbers=true,prenote=AA]
    \printbibliography[heading=none,resetnumbers=true,prenote=BB]
\end{document}
```

The example shows both methods.